# How to see the current playback speed in VLC?

Tags: vlc

On Windows, VLC's playback speed can be discovered on status bar, but the Mac version doesn't have a status bar. Where should I go to see the current playback speed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the Mac version of VLC, to see the playback speed, you have to click the Playback menu. It won't be shown on the default window.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 3):

You can also setup the OnScreenDisplay which will display playback speed changes, step forwards, step backwards and other changes during playback.

Go to VLC -> Preferences -> Subtitles/OSD -> Enable OSD.

Save settings and quit the vlc app so settings get applied.

Comment: This doesn't when playing audio without video, right?

Comment: My experience is that this doesn't work on Mac 12.2.1 with VLC 3.0.16. My OSD is enabled, but I still don't see any indication when I change playback speed.